# Matrices with eigenvalue of multiplicity $k$ are algebraic subset of special linear group.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology, resultant

In the previous exercise, I have showed that the special linear group $SL_n$ is a closed subvariety of $Mat(n,K)$ where $K$ is an algebraically closed field with characteristic zero. Now, I have to prove that the $SL_n^k$, the set of matrices $A \in SL_n$ with an eigenvalue of at least multiplicity $k$, is an algebraic subset of $SL_n$.

So far, I know that $\det(A-\lambda I)$ splits in linear terms and one term has multiplicity of at least $k$. However, the hint is to use the resultant of two polynomials but I have no idea how I'm able to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two tricks combine to solve this problem. The first is to observe that over a field of characteristic zero, a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ having a root $a$ of multiplicity $r$ is exactly equivalent to all derivatives up to order $r-1$ having $a$ as a root and the $r$th derivative not having $\lambda$ as a root if $r<d$. The second is that two polynomials $p(x),q(x)$ have a common root iff the resultant $Res_x(p(x),q(x))$ is zero.

To apply this to our situation, we consider the ideal generated by $Res_\lambda(\chi(\lambda),\chi(\lambda)^{(a)})$ for $0 < a < k$ where $\chi(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial in the variable $\lambda$. Since these resultants are polynomials in the coefficients of the (derivatives of the) characteristic polynomial, which are themselves polynomials in the entries of the matrix, we see that we've got a perfectly good ideal of the coordinate algebra of $Mat(n,k)$ and that $V$ of this ideal exactly corresponds to those matrices with a repeated eigenvalue of order $k$.

Comment: Why do we need to consider the resultant of every derivative of the characteristic polynomial? Is it not enough to look at the resultant of $\chi(\lambda)$ and $\chi(\lambda)^{(k)}$?

Comment: I'm also confused by another thing, if $a$ is a root of multiplicity $r$, then the derivatives up to order $r-1$ have $a$ as a root but that of order $r$ not. Is this just a typo in your response or am I missing something else?

Comment: Yes, I made an off-by-one error in the post with regards to $r$ versus $r+1$. It's been fixed. As for considering multiple resultants, think about the polynomial $x^4+x$. It has no repeated roots, and the resultant of it with it's derivative is nonzero ($-27$, actually) as you would expect. But it's second derivative is $12x^2$, which does share a root with the original polynomial. So only considering $Res(f,f^{(2)})$ would identify it as a polynomial with a repeated root, which is clearly incorrect. You do need the intermediate resultants.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. One more question though, can you compute these generating ideals in a relative fast and easy way? Because I tried to do it for $n=k=2$ which is not that hard but now I'm really struggling for $n=3$ and $k=2$

Comment: Computing with resultants is usually pretty awful - I'd get a computer algebra system to do it for you. ([Wolfram Alpha knows how to do it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx%5E3%2Bax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%2CD%5Bx%5E3%2Bax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%2Cx%5D%5D) for instance.) If you're looking to do it by hand, I'd start with writing out your characteristic polynomial as $(x-a)^2(x-a^{-2})$ and going from there - please let me know if that's what you're trying to do and you're still stuck and I'll see if I can't find something to say.

Comment: The Wolfram Alpha program helps a lot, thanks! One more question though, is there an easy way to check whether $SL_n^k$ is a variety and what their dimension is? Because I think that the polynomials are indeed irreducible but I can't think of an easy way to calculate their dimension.

Comment: I'm not sure about irreducibility (I presume this is what you're asking for when you ask about whether it's a variety). For dimensions, it should be the case that each $SL_n^k$ should be codimension $k-1$ - the ideal cutting it out is given by $k-1$ functions, so it's at most codimension $k-1$, and $Res(\chi,\chi^{(a)})$ isn't in the ideal generated by the resultants of $\chi$ with $\chi^{(b)}$ for $b<a$ (there are points in the variety where it doesn't vanish, for instance), so the dimension drops by 1 for each such equation.