# Describe the associated ideals of these algebraic subsets of $SL_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $M_n$ be the set of all $( n \times n)$ matrices with coefficients in an algebraically closed field $K$. Identify $M_n$ with the affine space $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$.

If we denote by $SL_n$ the set of $(n \times n)$ matrices with determinant $1$, then this is a closed subvariety of $M_n$.

Let $SL_n^{k}$ be the set of matrices $A$ in $SL_n$ such that $A$ has an eigenvalue of multiplicity at least $k$ for an integer $1 \leq k \leq n$. Then $SL_n^k$ is an algebraic subset of $SL_n$ .

**Problem:** Describe the associated ideal of $SL_n^k$ for $2 \leq n \leq 4$. Are these $SL_n^{k}$ varieties? What are their dimension?

**Attempt:**

I was trying to understand these ideals for the simplest case $n = 2$. Then I have $SL_2^1$ and $SL_2^2$. A matrix $A \in SL_2^1$ is a $(2 \times 2)$ matrix with determinant $1$, and such that its characteristic polynomial $P_A(x) = \det(A - x I) \in K[x]$ splits in two linear factors over $K$ (since the eigenvalues must be of multiplicity $1$).

The associated ideal of $SL_2^1$ would be $$ I (SL_2^1) = \left\{ f \in K[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4] \mid f(A) = 0, \ \forall A \in SL_2^1 \right\}$$ where a 'point' $A \in SL_2^1$ is considered as a matrix.

How do I work this out further?

Comment: You're aware that over an alg. closed field, the characteristic polynomial splits in to a product of linear factors, right? Try writing out the linear factors and seeing what bonus relations you get on the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial when you get repeated roots. You'll want to remember that determinant should be 1 as you're working with $SL$. (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425652/matrices-with-eigenvalue-of-multiplicity-k-are-algebraic-subset-of-special-lin/3426439#3426439) for the general case, but you should do well to just write things out here.)

Comment: I'd like to help you by answering this question, but in order to write a good answer, I need to know what you're having trouble with. Have you perused the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425652/matrices-with-eigenvalue-of-multiplicity-k-are-algebraic-subset-of-special-lin/3426439#3426439) from the above comment? If so, what parts of that answer do you not understand (or otherwise need help with)?

Comment: I just don't know what to calculate. Maybe you can give an example of the calculation for $n = 2$.

Comment: For example, for $SL_2^2$, I require a repeated root. The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2 + (-a_{22} - a_{11}) \lambda + a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21}$. Do I calculate the resultant of this and its first derivative $2 \lambda + (-a_{22} - a_{21})$?

Comment: What do we require for $SL_2^{1}$? There is no resultant to calculate then?

Comment: Well, think about what $SL_n^1$ is. It's matrices with at least one eigenvalue of multiplicity $1$. But this just means the matrix has an eigenvalue - this is trivially satisfied over an algebraically closed field. I've posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [my other answer on this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425652/matrices-with-eigenvalue-of-multiplicity-k-are-algebraic-subset-of-special-lin/3426439#3426439), the ideal of $SL^k_n$ is generated by $$Res_\lambda(\chi(\lambda),\chi(\lambda)^{(a)})$$ for $0 < a < k$ where $\chi(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial in the variable $\lambda$. Let's work through an example or two to see how it works:

Case 0: $SL_2^1$. This is the whole of $SL_2$, since every matrix has an eigenvalue of multiplicity at least one. So the ideal is just the zero ideal. This generalizes to $SL_n^1$ for any $n$.

Case 1: $SL_2^2$. Here, the characteristic polynomial is given by $\lambda^2-(a_{11}+a_{22})\lambda + (a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12}a_{21})$. The derivative of this is $2\lambda-(a_{11}+a_{22})$, and the resultant of these two polynomials is $-a_{11}^2+2a_{11}a_{22}-4a_{12}a_{21}-a_{22}^2$. Remembering that we're in $SL_2$ where $a_{11}a_{22} - a_{12}a_{21}=1$, we can write the resultant as $$-a_{11}^2-2a_{11}a_{22}+4a_{11}a_{22}-4a_{12}a_{21}-a_{22}^2 =-a_{11}^2-2a_{11}a_{22}+4-a_{22}^2= -(a_{11}+a_{22})^2+4$$

so we know that the ideal cut out by this resultant is exactly those matrices of trace $\pm 2$, which in $SL_2$ are exactly those matrices which have both eigenvalues $1$ or both eigenvalues $-1$, which are the matrices in $SL_2$ with repeated eigenvalues.

We can see that this matches up exactly with what we'd expect to see from writing the characteristic polynomial as $\lambda^2-(x_1+x_2)\lambda+x_1x_2$ where the $x_i$ are the eigenvalues. If $x_1=x_2$ and $x_1x_2=1$, then $x_1=x_2=\pm 1$.

For larger $n$, these resultants will get really messy really fast. For instance, when expanded out, the resultant of the characteristic polynomial with it's derivative for any matrix in $SL_3$ has more than a hundred terms. It's best to use computer algebra systems for this if you're interested in actually doing these computations.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to compute the resultant for $n = 3$ with Wolfram alpha, but it doesn't recognize the expression...